# How can I know how much <a> tags I have in my document

Tags: javascript, html

how can I know how much `<a>` tags I have in my document, using JavaScript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').length
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns a list of all the elements of that tag, and `length` tells you how many there are.

[Here is some documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName).

---

You can also count the amount of links in a certain element, for example:

```
<div id='yourDiv'>
    <a href='link1'>link1</a>
    <a href='link2'>link2</a>
</div>
<a href='link3'>link3</a>
```

And the script:

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById('yourDiv')
var linkCount = yourDiv.getElementsByTagName('a').length
console.log(linkCount) // 2
```

Comment: Can anyone remember when you had to encapulate it in parentheses?  Was it IE6 that you had to `(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).length`?  Maybe I'm just going crazy

Comment: @vol7ron Uhh... I have no idea :P

Comment: You can also chain: `document.getElementById('yourDiv').getElementsByTagName('a').length;`

Comment: @vol7ron Better to break it up for clarity to user2701524, and to avoid horizontal scrolling in Stack Overflow's code blocks

Comment: @Doorknob Not necessarily, but it doesn't hurt. It's only a 3-chainer  and 4-or-less is generally acceptable especially when the method names are so descriptive

Comment: @vol7ron Well, the main reason was just to get it to fit within the code block without horizontal scrolling :P I would definitely chain if I were writing this for a website or something though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someID a').length
```

Using jQuery of course.

Comment: Okay thanks, can I specify it, like the only <a> tags that are the child of an "element by id"?

Comment: Updated my jQuery answer in response to the comment.